# Как реализовать "рисование" во Flash с последующим сохранением данных в файл?

Tags: flash, php

Здравствуйте, интересует такой вопрос. Нужно реализовать на сайте некую "доску рисования", на которой можно будет рисовать (ну очевидно, же). Данные должны сохранятся в виде картинки .png формата (то есть с прозрачностью). Есть ли какие-нибудь исходники сея чуда?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Советую вот такую библиотечку: [The Graffiti AS3 Bitmap Drawing Library](http://www.nocircleno.com/graffiti/)

Использовал в проекте для вконтакта, сохранял не напрямую в файл, а на сервер. Довольно приличная рисовалка получилась.
Класс для декодирования bitmap - `PNGEncoder`.

Comment: спасибо, то что нужно!

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите компоненты flash и методы самого canvas. Возможно есть такая возможность как в GDI с их метаформатом.